# Installing Membase from source

Tags: installation, membase

I am trying to build and install *membase* from source tarball. The steps I followed are:

1. Un-archive the tar `membase-server_src-1.7.1.1.tar.gz`
2. Issue `make` (from within the untarred folder)

Once done, I enter into directory install/bin and invoke the script `membase-server`.

This starts up the server with a message:

> The maximum number of open files for the membase user is set too low.
>   It must be at least 10240. Normally this can be increased by adding
>   the following lines to /etc/security/limits.conf:

Tried updating `limits.conf` as suggested, but no luck it continues to pop up the same message and continues booting

Given that the server is started I tried accessing *memcached* over port 11211, but I get a *connection refused* message. Then figured out (`netstat`) that *memcached* is listening to 11210 and tried telneting to port 11210, unfortunately the connection is closed as soon as I issue the following commands

```
stats    
set myvar 0 0 5
```

Note: I am not getting any output from the commands above {Yes: `stats` did not show anything but still I issued `set`.}

Could somebody help me build and install *membase* from source? Also why is *memcached* listening to 11210 instead of 11211?

It would be great if somebody could also give me a step-by-step guide which I can follow to build from source from Git repository (I have not used `autoconf` earlier).

P.S: I have tried installing from binaries (debian package) on the same machines and I am able to successfully install and telnet. Hence not sure why is build from source not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of file descriptors on your machine by using the ulimit command. Try doing (you might need to use sudo as well):

ulimit -n 10240

I personally have this set in my .bash_rc so that whenever I start my terminal it is always set for me.

Also, memcached listens on port 11210 by default for Membase. This is done because Moxi, the memcached proxy server, listens on port 11211. I'm also pretty sure that the memcached version used for Membase only listens for the binary protocol so you won't be able to successfully telnet to 11210 and have commands work correctly. Telneting to 11211 (moxi) should work though.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I had posted this same issue on Membase forum too, we found that libconflate was not built and hence moxi was down. When trying to find the reason for libconflate not being built I found the following errors in my config.log
> ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory

> minix/config.h: No such file or directory

> error: '__SUNPRO_C' undeclared
> error: '__ICC' undeclared

Any idea why is this error seen. Googling around I found that this could be issue realted to gcc. I upgraded gcc but still no difference in the output. I upgraded my Ubuntu to 11.04 still having hard luck.

Comment: Sorry about the editing. It is tossed up a bit and my time limit of 5 min was overshooted